# Code breaks in OpenCV

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, opencv, computer-vision

I am writing a opencv code to reshape my matrix from a channel to a single channel matrix with 3 columns.

```
uchar* ptrimage=(uchar*)image->imageData;
    uchar* ptrZ=(uchar*)Z->imageData;

    for (int i=0;i<image->height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<image->width;j++)
        {

            for(int k=0;k<image->nChannels;k++)
            {
                cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<" "<<k<<endl;
                (ptrZ+(j+i*image->width)*Z->widthStep)[k]=(ptrimage+i*image->widthStep)[3*j+k];

            }

        }
```

Z is the new matrix I want to get whose height is image->width*imgae->height and width is 3.
This breaks after 7-8 iterations of j.Can you please help me find the error.

Comment: How did you create your matrices (update your post with this information)? And could you post your error message?

Comment: well I fixed the error.I created a transpose of what I wanted to create since I am used to MATLAb